# Stripe - Retrieve Customer PaymentIntent history

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am building a platform where I am using Stripe's concept of a parent "platform" account and Connected Stripe accounts that belong to this platform. (e.g. Lyft model) Following Stripe's documentation, when I create a new customer in Stripe, I create it under the main platform account and also store all the payment methods under that customer. When a customer buys something from the Connected account, I follow [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) doc, where I clone payment method and create a PaymentIntent that is attached to the specific Connected account. And it all works. However, when I try to get a history of customer's transactions (List of PaymentIntents), it returns an empty list because it runs it against the main platform account:

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.list(customer='cus_FJDHFGSJHDF')
```

When I specify a customer AND connected account id, it returns an empty list, because that customer doesn't exist in that Connected account, however, the paymentIntents are present in that Connected account.

**So, what is the right way to create a PaymentIntent for a customer for a Connected account and then get the history of payments for that customer PER Connected Stripe account?**

Here is how I clone PaymentMethod and create PaymentIntent:

```
payment_method = stripe.PaymentMethod.create(
        customer=customer,
        payment_method=customer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method,
        stripe_account=stripe_connect_id,
    )


    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        payment_method=payment_method,
        amount=amount,
        currency='usd',
        confirm=True,
        application_fee_amount=fee_in_cents if fee_in_cents >= 1 else None,
        stripe_account=stripe_connect_id,
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I decided to take. Since I specifically was interested in pulling Charges that the specific customer made in the specific Connected account, I've read up more on Charges and noticed that you can get a list of charges based on `transfer_group='{ORDER10}'`. So, here is my flow:

- Customer and customer's payment methods are stored under the main platform account (so that I can keep track of the current default payment method in one place)
- When a customer makes a payment to a specific Connected account, I clone their default payment method
- Create a PaymentIntent and set `transfer_group` to the customer's phone number as it is a unique identifier throughout my platform.

Now, when I need to pull all charges for a specific customer, I loop through each Connected account that the customer is associated with (this relationship is stored on my platform) and simply pull all Charges using `transfer_group` and `stripe_account_id`:

```
def get_all_charges(user, stripe_account_id):
     return stripe.Charge.list(transfer_group=user.phone_number, stripe_account=stripe_account_id, limit=100).data
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you have 2 options:

1. Create the Customers on the connected Account and create charges there, then you have the relationship [0].
2. Save the customer id in metadata of the PaymentIntent and then reconcile them in your code [1].

Hope that helps!

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods#making-a-charge

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Comment: Thanks v3nkman! About 1: This was my first decision and I actually started implementing it. But then I realized that I will have to store the payment methods per Connected account which I don't like since I want to store payments in one place on the platform level.
About 2: Original idea. I like it. But then if I want to pull all transactions for one customer, it looks like I will have to get all transactions for that Connected account and then filter out by customer id in metadata. This seems to be very inefficient.